# Como apago cookies no node.js quando o utlizador sair do site?

Tags: node.js, express.js, cookies

Eu estou a definir uma cookie no node.js quando o utilizador escolhe a linguagem:

```
res.cookie('lang', req.body.lang)
```

Mas eu queria apagar a cookie quando ele fechasse o site, para que quando ele voltasse a linguagem fosse a predefinida, é possivel fazer isso? só encontrei respostas para session cookies.

Answer (score -1):

A função **clearCookie** pode te ajudar, vou dar um códico de exemplo:

```
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
// Remove o cachê do usuário
users.splice(
users.findIndex((obj => 
obj.profile.oid == 
req.user.profile.oid)), 1);
req.session.destroy( (err) => {
req.logOut();
res.clearCookie('graphNodeCookie');
res.status(200);
res.redirect('http://localhost:' + port);
 });
});
```

**Fonte**:https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-clear-cookie

Comment: Mas eu queria apagar as cookies quando o utilizador fechasse o separador por exemplo, não tenho nenhuma opção para fazer logout

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso com cookies, somente com sessões.